# Failed to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, wireless

My company uses WPA2 Enterprise encryption for employees to login to their wireless. In NetworkManager I have filled out all of the required fields:

- Security : WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- Authentication : Protected EAP (PEAP)
- CA certificate is not needed
- PEAP version : Automatic
- Inner authentication : MSCHAPv2
- Username and Password are correct.

Every time that I try to connect, I get a window asking me to input my password over and over again.

The same configuration is working in OS X and also my Android phone, but it never works on Windows nor Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it worked, but apparently my office-mate was able to resolve this issue by deleting the saved network connection and then using the "Connect to Hidden Network" menu to setup the connection. This menu can be accessed by clicking the wifi icon on the top bar.

For whatever reason, this seemed to resolve the issue for them. It's a poor answer and without justification, but maybe it'll work for you too. Although I'm more than a month late.